# Google Map Displaying Grey Squares

Tags: android, google-maps

I've made a very simple app that just displays a Google map.  However, it only seems to be displaying gray squares.

I've troubleshooted and have done virtually everything I could.  I checked my code 5+ times over, I've compared it even to other tutorials.  I've re-made my API key 3 times - none of them work.

The phone I'm using is connected to wireless.  Even the emulator won't work.  I have the library and permission established in the manifest.  I think I've done just about everything, but it still doesn't work... any suggestions?

Here's my code:

MapsActivity.java:

```
package net.learn2develop.GoogleMaps;

import com.google.android.maps.MapActivity;
import com.google.android.maps.MapView;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class MapsActivity extends MapActivity 
{    
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
    }

    @Override
    protected boolean isRouteDisplayed() {
        return false;
    }
}
```

main.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">

    <com.google.android.maps.MapView 
        android:id="@+id/mapView"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:apiKey="0duU2_tgS67qkUZIpmLVIo0IDvJDh4Ew1Mzh9Pg"
        />
</RelativeLayout>
```

GoogleMapsManifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      package="net.learn2develop.GoogleMaps"
      android:versionCode="1"
      android:versionName="1.0.0">
    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="7" />
    <application android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/app_name">

    <uses-library android:name="com.google.android.maps" />  

        <activity android:name=".MapsActivity"
                  android:label="@string/app_name">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

</manifest>
```

Comment: did you make the api key with the debug keystore?

Comment: you have to make 2 different api keys, one for debug for running with eclipse and one for release.

Comment: How do I make a debug key?  And are you saying that I need this debug key to run the app myself on Eclipse, but the other key is for if I were to release my app only?

Comment: yes. Windows > Preferences > Android > Build. That's where you can find the location of the debug keystore. do the same process, just with this keystore instead of the one you generated for your app. The reason you need 2 is because eclipse signs the apk with a different signature than if you were to sign it yourself for release.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was that Mike was using an API key generated with the release keystore instead of the debug keystore that eclipse uses when compiling the apk.

Comment: hey i m getting same issue can u plz tell me what is release keystore and debug keystore ...i m just making api key from pref->Android->built (sha1) for mapv2 and testing apllication directly running from eclipse

Answer (score 2):

You need to add

```
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
```

into you manifest

Note: If you are using both `NETWORK_PROVIDER` and `GPS_PROVIDER`, then you need to request only the `ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION` permission, because it includes permission for both providers. (Permission for `ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION` includes permission only for `NETWORK_PROVIDER`.)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error ! I tried everything, so a try this tutorial below and it worked!!!!

[TUTORIAL](http://www.mobitechie.com/android-2/android-how-to-generate-google-api-key-for-android-google-maps/)